# iPhone - encoding and decoding a NSValue

Tags: iphone, cocoa, quartz-graphics, cglayer

So I read here on SO that I can encode a CGLayerRef to a NSValue using

```
NSValue *myCopy = [[NSValue alloc] initWithBytes:&myLayer objCType:@encode(CGLayerRef)];
```

but how do I recreate the CGLayerRef from myCopy?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
CGLayerRef giveMeBackTheLayer;
[myCopy getValue:&giveMeBackTheLayer];
```

Comment: just a bit off topic... do you know how can I discover the number of bytes myCopy is using?... thanks.

Comment: @Digital The number of bytes in the whole instance or the number of bytes needed to store a `CGLayerRef`? It’s probably a combination of `class_getInstanceSize()` and `sizeof CGLayerRef`. The actual layer `struct` is opaque, though.

Comment: You'd need to store that information separately. You can't get it from the `NSValue`.

Comment: @Bavarious - the number of bytes needed to store CGLayerRef

Comment: @Digi `sizeof CGLayerRef`, then. Note that `CGLayerRef` is a pointer, so it has the same size as any other pointer in your target platform: 32 bits.